# Erorr in the swift code

Tags: swift

```
typealias NetworkResponse = (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?)

extension NSURLSession {

func sendSynchronousDataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NetworkResponse? {

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var response: NetworkResponse? = nil

    let task = dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data :NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        response = NetworkResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    return response
 }

}
```

Unable to assign value to response variable inside block in swift. Missing the keyword __block in swift

the error is:

> Cannot assign to value: 'response' is a 'let' constant

Comment: rename var response, now you are trying to assign input parameter of the closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typealias NetworkResponse = (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?)

extension NSURLSession {

func sendSynchronousDataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NetworkResponse? {

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var res: NetworkResponse? = nil

    let task = dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data :NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        res = NetworkResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    task.resume()
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    return res
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `response` to variable:

```
let task = dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data :NSData?, var response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Like this

Comment: While technically correct, the issue the OP is having is that they have 2 `response` variables. One they created and one they receive back in the `dataTaskWithRequest` method.